# How to detect all points of rectangle by given one point A, height, width, and angle between AC and X axis?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

How to detect points B, C, D of rectangle with given point A, height, width and angle L between AC and X axis.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ x_C= x_A + w \cos L ;   y_C= y_A + w \sin L $$

similarly for $B$.

Let the fourth point be D.

Since the average of opposites points ( center of gravity) is $0$, ( same

for either x or y), we have for points $D$ and $B$

$$ x_D= x_B+ x_C-x_A; y_D= y_B+ y_C-y_A.  $$

Answer (score 0):

Let A = (0, 0). Answers follow if the lengths of each red line segments are known.

[image]